# Scanner Software with OCR Filename

Tags: pdf, ocr, scanning, filenames

I am scanning several documents that are the same format with different names. I'm looking for a program that will scan these and output the file name via OCR from the name on the document.

We had an old Panasonic scanner that used do this with its Image Capture Plus software. I was able to define an area for it to OCR and it then saved the file name as what it read. I have not been able to find equivalent software to this unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to software recommendations. Which OS and what budget do you have?

Comment: The OS would be Windows 7 and as far as budget I would like to keep it as small as possible. I would need to install this on multiple PC's so I need to keep the price low. I would like to keep it below $150.00 if that is possible.